# Proving the limit of a convergent series is unique

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

If a series converges to a limit $L\in \Bbb{R}$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=L$$

then the sequence of partial sums {$s_n$} converges to $L$ as well, that is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = L$$

Now If I have understood correctly, from here the proof is *exactly the same* as the proof, which states that the limit of a convergent sequence is unique. As the proof is quite well-known I don't think it is necessary to post the whole thing here. I will mention the basics for context. We assume there is another limit for $s_n=$ $M\neq L$, then define $$\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\vert L-M \vert$$

which leads to the contradiction $$\vert L-M \vert< \epsilon + \epsilon$$

Can the uniqueness of the limit of a convergent series be proven in this vein?

Comment: Absolutely. In fact, the sum of an infinite series is typically defined to be the limit of the **sequence** of partial sums, in the usual sequential definition of limits. So, uniqueness of infinite sums of convergent series follows immediately from uniqueness of limits of convergent sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion

> Every convergent series has a unique sum.

is a particular case of the assertion

> Every convergent sequence has a unique limit.

since asserting that a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges is (by definition) *equivalent* to the assertion that the sequence $\left(\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$ converges. So, the best option here is to use the statement about sequences to prove the statement concerning series.